# PyTorch RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (4) must match the size of tensor b (0) at non-singleton dimension 1

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection

I need to build a object detection model and I am following this tutorial https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NziO_b-SW9KmWFh-6C8to9H_QAdpmCBZ

Then I would like to plot a graph which can shows the training and validation loss. However, when i try to implement this validate function, the system output the runtime error.

```
def validate(model, data_loader, device):
    model.eval()  # set the model to evaluation mode
    valid_losses = []
    with torch.no_grad():  # disable gradient computation
        for images, targets in data_loader:
            images = list(image.to(device) for image in images)
            targets = [{k: v.to(device) for k, v in t.items()} for t in targets]
            loss_dict = model(images, targets)
            #losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
            losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict[0].values())
            loss_value = losses.item()
            valid_losses.append(loss_value)  # append the validation loss value to the valid_losses list
    return sum(valid_losses) / len(valid_losses)  # return the average validation loss
```

Here is i call for the validate function

```
num_epochs = 1

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # training for one epoch
    train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)

    # update the learning rate
    lr_scheduler.step()

    # validate on the val dataset
    validate(model, data_loader_val, device=device)
    # evaluate on the val dataset
    evaluate(model, data_loader_val, device=device)
```

Here is the system error

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-9becf22a9df7> in <cell line: 3>()
      9 
     10     # validate on the val dataset
---> 11     validate(model, data_loader_val, device=device)
     12     # evaluate on the val dataset
     13     evaluate(model, data_loader_val, device=device)

<ipython-input-8-d0685d84ac9a> in validate(model, data_loader, device)
     10             print(type(loss_dict))
     11             #losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict.values())
---> 12             losses = sum(loss for loss in loss_dict[0].values())
     13             loss_value = losses.item()
     14             valid_losses.append(loss_value)  # append the validation loss value to the valid_losses list

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (4) must match the size of tensor b (16) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

How could I fix it? Does anyone can help me?